# Implementing Game Center in my ios app

Tags: ios, center

I am trying to implement game center in my new app, I am following a tutorial from

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/

I am following the same procedure but unfortunately I am not able to sove it here is my code

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else{
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;

                // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {

                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else{
                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                    }
                }];
            }

            else{
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I am on the first step and I am authenticating the player but when i build and run as described in the tutorial I see the errors on lines where it says "use of undeclared identifiers.

```
_gameCenterEnabled = YES; ------ Use of undeclared identifier '_gameCenterEnabled'

_leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;----- Use of undeclared identifier 'leaderboardIdentifier'

_gameCenterEnabled = NO;---- Use of undeclared identifier '_gameCenterEnabled'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `_gameCenterEnabled` and `_leaderboardIdentifier` as properties first.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *leaderboardIdentifier;
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL gameCenterEnabled;
```

Comment: Yeaaa Thanks alot that worked, it removed the errors but as explained in the tutorial it doesn't show up game center in the game, I see my game in the simulator same as before ....

Comment: It still does not authenticatie local player when i build and run the project even it if it gives no error messages please help me put game center on my game please